# "The selected data source is on remote computer" error when creating an SSIS job

Tags: sql-server-2005, ssis, import, flat-file, dataflowtask

I am in the process of developing an SSIS job on my workstation which a Data Flow Task open a comma delimited flat file on my local workstation and imports the data to a SQL server database on a remote server.

When I try to select the destination table in my SQL destination object, it gives me the following error:

> The selected data source is on a
>   remote computer.  The bulk insert
>   operation can be executed on the local
>   computer.

How do I resolve the issue so I can test my SSIS package.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The SQL Server destination only works if the package is running on the same machine as the specified database server. To use remote connections, change to an OleDb destination instead.

Comment: This was the problem, useless "SQL Server destination", thanks!